# Вывод количества значений из 1 поля

Tags: php, sql

в таблице имеется поле type, в нем может быть 1 из 4 значения (start, stop, reset, ok). необходимо вывести сколько раз например start и stop. 1 человеку например принадлежит 3 строки и в этих двух строках в поле type присутствует start(2) и stop(2) и соответственно должно вывести start:2 stop:2. Помогите с логикой, сильно запутался какой проверкой можно это сделать.
Вывод из бд идет в виде двухмерного массива

Comment: `GROUP BY` + `COUNT()`

Comment: @Akina, отсортирует и выведет общее количество, а нужно отдельно считать, или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Думаю, Вам будет полезно прочитать что-нибудь про группировку и использование агрегатных функций, какой-нить обучающий курс или книжку, примеры разобрать оттуда... а при чём тут сортировка, я вообще не понял.